# My laptop lost power after i accidentally plug in speaker cords to usb drive

Tags: http-referrer

What possible damage might have done to my laptop after i accidentally plug in my speaker cords to my laptops usb drive because immediately after contact with the speaker cord the laptop lost power.  The speaker was powered on when i tried to hook it in my laptop..is it possible that my motherboard got fried and beyond repair, or maybe just an IC got damage, please help...

Comment: is the laptop working now (with the speakers disconnected) or not?

Answer (score 3):

You shorted the +5V rail to ground, causing the system to lose power and shut down. This should cause no lasting damage unless the machine was already having power issues to begin with.